# Jenkins HTTPS Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins

[image]im trying to connect my Github repo to Jenkins and I keep getting this :

"Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git.exe ls-remote -h"

what is it exactly and how I can solve the problem .

I tried HTTPS and SSH but it makes no different.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to define the path of the installed git.exe.

Navigate to:

`Manage Jenkins` -> `Global Tool Configuration` -> `Git` -> `Path to Git executable`

and add the path of the git installed in your Jenkins system.

eg.

[image: git path]

Answer (score 0):

You could be using older version of git,
I had resolved this problem by updating to `2.12.2` version.